Debian backports: How do I list all available upgrades from bullseye-backports
I've searched unsuccessfully for a method to list all of the upgrades available from Debian's backports (specifically bullseye-backports):

I've added deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free to /etc/apt/sources.list.

I've run sudo apt update successfully

I've run sudo apt list --upgradeable bullseye-backports with an "empty" result

I've run sudo apt list --upgradeable -t bullseye-backports; got an error

I've run sudo apt -t bullseye-backports upgrade; I get a list of NEW packages to be installed, and a list of EXISTING packages to be upgraded, and a [Y/n] option to proceed with the entire lot.


Is there no way to simply list the upgrade-able packages from bullseye-backports?

aptitude can list all upgradeable packages, including candidates from backports:
aptitude -t bullseye-backports search '~U'

If you want to see only upgrades from backports, add an archive filter:
aptitude -t bullseye-backports search '~U~Abullseye-backports'

Note that backports aren’t tested together, so as a general rule it’s best to only upgrade packages you really need from backports. You shouldn’t try to actually apply anything equivalent to apt -t bullseye-backports upgrade. (I’m not suggesting that’s what you’re thinking of doing, but other readers might not realise that this isn’t recommended.)

Your statement "best to only upgrade packages you really need from backports" was prescient! Please see my next question. I thought the udev upgrade would be "safe", but I guess I was wrong!
